# Blazor - Drag and Drop uploads file

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, blazor, .net-6.0

I'm facing an issue with uploading a file via the Drag'n Drop API.
Here the following blazor component:

```
 <InputTextArea
        @ondrop="HandleDrop"
        @ondragenter="HandleDragEnter"
        @ondragleave="HandleDragLeave"/>
 </InputTextArea>

@code {
    private async Task HandleDrop(DragEventArgs args)
    {
        var files = args.DataTransfer.Files;
        // Do something to upload the file and get the content
    }
```

I want to upload the file and display it in the textarea. Now since .NET6 the `DragEventArgs` will list all files (if any) associated with the Drag'n Drop event.
Natively there seems to be no way to get the content of those files.

Therefore I tried to achieve this with JavaScript interop:

```cs
private async Task HandleDrop(DragEventArgs args)
{
    var content = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getContentFromFile", args);
}
```

With the following JavaScript function (which is referenced in the `_Layout.cshtml`):

```js
async function getContentFromFile(args) {
    // Use some API here? File Upload API? Didn't work as args is only a data object and not the "real" DragEventArgs from JavaScript

    // I also tried FileReader
    const fileName = args.Files[0]; // Let's assume we always have one file
    let content = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (e) => resolve(fileReader.result);
        fileReader.readAsText(fileName);
    });

    console.log(content);
    return content;

}
```

This approach let to other issues and exceptions, like that the `FileReader` threw:

> parameter is not of type 'Blob'

Is this with this approach with the current version of blazor (.net6) possible at all? Any tips are welcome.

Comment: Is it not something you'd do in the OnChange of an InputFile?

Comment: Just did a quick test, chucked `<InputFile OnChange="@LoadFilesAsync" multiple/>` into the razor and a `private async Task LoadFilesAsync(InputFileChangeEventArgs e) { foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles(5)){ Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream(2048000);` in the code, it started uploading when i dropped a file on the "Choose files" button (the only visible part of the inputfile)..

Comment: Yes it works with InputFile. I want to have this explicitly on a textarea, if this is possible.